# When you finish the mission Innocence Lost, how do you find Astrid?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After you finish the mission Innocence Lost, how do you find Astrid?

Comment: What has happened?  You'll have to give us more information

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! For any future questions you have about Skyrim, I suggest you first look at either [The Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_Wiki) or [The Elder Scrolls Pages](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skyrim). Anybody here is just going to look there first, as your answerer here did. Most of what you need to know will already be written up there. If you look there and don't find it, let us know in your question and you'll get better answers and more votes.

Comment: You don't.  Astrid finds you.

Answer (score 3):

After you finish Innocence Lost, a courier will deliver a note to you with the words "We Know."  Afterwards, you need to sleep.  Astrid will come and kidnap you in your sleep to start the quest [With Friends Like These...](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:With_Friends_Like_These...)

There are some reports of not needing the note in order to be kidnapped, so you can just try sleeping after telling Aventus Aretino that Grelod is dead, but I've always gotten the note shortly after the quest is resolved.